# jQuery: Dropdown "option:first-child" as selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown and I want to make my jquery code generally for other applications.
So I have a selector for this field which is called

```
$('#myList option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected').
```

I also have a `var` for the field `#myList` which looks like this:

`var myDropdown = $('#myList')`.

Is it now possible to do someting like this:

`myDropdown.option:first-child.attr('selected', 'selected')`.

Because then, my code would be reusable. Thanks!!

Comment: You might want something like `myDropdown.find('option:first-child').attr('selected', 'selected')`

Comment: `myDropdown.find('option:first-child').prop('selected', true)`

Comment: You can also try `$('option:first-child',myDropdown).prop('selected', true)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
var myDropdown = $('#myList');

$('option:first-child',myDropdown).prop('selected', true);
```